# Codeigniter $config['uri_protocol'] problem

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I need to change  `$config['uri_protocol']` from AUTO to PATH_INFO (to allow url parameters)

My problem: when I set `$config['uri_protocol']="PATH_INFO";` the regular urls stop functioning and I get the homepage no matter which site page URL I click.

print_r ($_SERVER) shows that url parameters I add appear only in REQUEST_URI an not in any other $_SERVER part.

my htaccess is the [standard one](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # This is different between local host and production server!!!
    RewriteBase /


    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

UPDATE:

I changed

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

to
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]`  to allow url params to pass. Now url params appear also in

```
 $_SERVER

 REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING, QUERY_STRING AND REQUEST_URI
```

.

The problem: I tried $config[‘uri_protocol’] with all the above options but still CI gives error 404 whenever I add URL parameters.

Note: I tried the above on 2 servers. One of them is centos5/Apache2/Plesk VPS and another one is on xampp/Vista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[how to remove url parameters in htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880807/how-to-remove-url-parameters-in-htaccess)

Comment: Hey, I just found this question through Google. I'm having exactly the same problem that you describe here. I need to use URL query strings but if I change $config[‘uri_protocol’] to "PATH_INFO" (which is needed to allow the query string to work), all of my pages simply redirect to the home page.

Now I followed your link that you've supplied here but I don't understand your solution (and it doesn't seem to work for me). Can I ask what did you set $config[‘uri_protocol’] to and what does your .htaccess look like now?

Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Sorry about that, I figured out a solution (hack hack hack :P). My host (for some reason) doesn't allow the PATH_INFO variable. So I just copied the ORIG_PATH_INFO value into the PATH_INFO variable. Et voila!

Comment: $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']; works nice

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and when i set uri_protocol to `PATH_INFO` then all the links of my site goes to default controller & action. Then i found that my server doesn't support `PATH_INO` variable, so i did two steps in `config.php` to solve the problem:

First:

```
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'];
```

Then:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

The above two lines solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the [QSA] option in your last rule from mod_rewrite...
This appends the query string arguments (I mean after the '?') to your final URL.

Your rule ends like this :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?baseurl=$1 [QSA,L]
```

If your request is :

```
http://yourhost.com/module/action?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

In the end, you get :

```
http://yourhost.com/index.php?baseurl=/module/action&param1=value1&param2=value2
```

*I haven't tested it. Is it what you really want ?*

Comment: Hi Arno,

Thanks for the tip. It did not solve the problem completely, please see the update in the original question.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the trailing slash between "?" and "$1" ?

Answer (score 1):

In which case you do not want to set $config['uri_protocol'] to PATH_INFO. var_dump($_SERVER) somewhere and find which variable contains your path as you want it, then set it to that, if AUTO does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to check which parameter you are getting from the server.

If you're getting `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`, use the following.

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

Otherwise, if you're getting `$_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']`, use this:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'ORIG_PATH_INFO';
```

Make these changes in your config file.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem: when I set `$config['uri_protocol']="PATH_INFO";` the regular urls stop functioning and I get the homepage no matter which site page URL I click.

This is probably because you're not actually passing the URL-path as PATH_INFO in your `RewriteRule` directive:

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
> ```

Here, the URL-path is being passed as a query_string and the path_info is *empty* (which would explain why all requests end up at your homepage). In this case you would need the additional `QSA` flag in order to *append* any additional query string from the request (as noted in your question).

To pass the URL-path as path_info (ie. *additional pathname information*), you need to remove the `?` from the `RewriteRule` *substitution*. (You then don't need the `QSA` flag since the query string from the request will be automatically passed through to the *substitution*.)

For example, to use PATH_INFO, construct the `RewriteRule` directive like this:

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

The regex `(.*)` is the same as `^(.*)$` since regex is greedy by default.

---

Note that your server must also be configured to accept path-info (otherwise it will trigger an automatic 404). By default this is dependent on the associated file handler. The handler associated with `.php` files will accept path-info by default. (`.html` files will not.) However, if you need to explicitly enable this then add the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
AcceptPathInfo On
```

This enables path-info for all URLs.