# Remove/ Redirect URL query string

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, query-string

Example: http://dearearth.net/news/**?cbg_tz=240**

Plugin site with query string example and explanation: http://plugins.righthere.com/custom-backgrounds/multiple-schedule/?cbg_tz=480

I had come across in the past of a way to remove the unwanted `?cbg_tz=240` which is appended to all the URL. This seems to be affecting my analytics and creating dupes wth/ without the string...

I believe it's fairly simple with an .htaccess edit. Anyone have the .htaccess settings which would accomplish this task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something similar: [how to remove url parameters in htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880807/how-to-remove-url-parameters-in-htaccess)

This should work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
    RewriteRule (.*) $1?
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I have the same issue. I have applied this answer and my site is working stop.