# codeigniter and its uri protocol

Tags: php, codeigniter

heres some code- when i change

```
$config['uri_protocol']  = "AUTO";
```

to

```
$config['uri_protocol']  = "PATH_INFO";
```

My controllers all default to the default controller.. hence domain.com/admin defaults to domain.com and domain.com/users defaults to the default controller

where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` or `getenv('PATH_INFO'])` actually set?  If everything goes to the default controller, then this should be because either the `PATH_INFO` variable is not being past as you expect, or there is an issue with the routing, which should result in the same situation on `AUTO`.

Comment: In which case you do not want to set `$config['uri_protocol']` to `PATH_INFO`.  var_dump($_SERVER) somewhere and find which variable contains your path as you want it, then set it to that, if `AUTO` does not work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I realised I needed to remove a slash from the htaccess file in order to enable path info to be passed into the index .php file

Comment: Quite alright, CodeIgniter is relatively fussy about the URLs incoming, but once it is setup and working it is usually fine.

Answer (score 1):

From CodeIgniter user guide:

> If you find that no matter what you put in your URL only your default
>   page is loading, it might be that your server does not support the
>   PATH_INFO variable needed to serve search-engine friendly URLs. As a
>   first step, open your application/config/config.php file and look for
>   the URI Protocol information. It will recommend that you try a couple
>   alternate settings. If it still doesn't work after you've tried this
>   you'll need to force CodeIgniter to add a question mark to your URLs.

Link: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem as you (are you using GoDaddy by any chance?), and the question below helped me:

See [Codeigniter $config['uri_protocol'] problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872505/codeigniter-configuri-protocolproblem). Look at the second answer, in the comments.