# CodeIgniter Change POST method URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

I basically have a search box on the index of my site and when a user tries to search anything 
the function q is called from the controller ( search.php ) and the method used by the form is  post so basically i end up with this following URL youdomain.com/search/q i wanted to get something like this youdomain.com/search/your-search-query.html i know this is possible using routes i tried search'ing alot but failed in getting something like this.

I dont wanna change my form method as if i change it to get i will need to also change the config.php URI to query which is kind of ugly .

So is there any solution to this ?

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: I already searched all that but how do i get it work with POST method :/ you can read the question again i clearly mentioned how the class is being called.

Comment: `$this->input->get('name-of-uri-query-variable')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A question: What do you want to happen if a user types in the address `youdomain.com/search/your-search-query.html` directly? If you want the search results also in this case (which is a right thing to do), you will have to implement GET search anyway.

I shouldn't be even telling you this, because it is in my opinion a bad thing to do here, but you can catch the submit event with javascript, change the url of the request and then send it.

Comment: I agree get is a bad way to go but i dont think i have any option right ?

Comment: i tried going to get but then when i try submitting from the form i get youdomain.com/search/q=query
how do i get just yourdomain.com/search/query-text.html? do i leave the input name blank ?

Comment: No, you missunderstood, I meant that GET is a good way to go here. Try setting `$config['uri_protocol']` in your `config/config.php` to `AUTO` or `PATH_INFO`. That should make it possible to send queries to this url: `youdomain.com/search/q/query_text`. If you want also the `.html` at the end, try `$config['url_suffix'] = '.html';`.
If it does not work, check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279904/codeigniter-and-its-uri-protocol