# $config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING'; Not allowing AJAX

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Some Ajax code I created, was working perfectly, but when I changed

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'auto';
```

into

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
```

it no longer works. Can anyone provide any suggestions?

---

This is what the comments say about the URI PROTOCOL

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URI PROTOCOL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This item determines which server global should be used to retrieve the
| URI string.  The default setting of 'AUTO' works for most servers.
| If your links do not seem to work, try one of the other delicious flavors:
|
| 'AUTO'            Default - auto detects
| 'PATH_INFO'       Uses the PATH_INFO
| 'QUERY_STRING'    Uses the QUERY_STRING
| 'REQUEST_URI'     Uses the REQUEST_URI
| 'ORIG_PATH_INFO'  Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO
|
*/
```

Comment: Provide your `ajax` code

Comment: Have you tried this: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/troubleshooting.html ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279904/codeigniter-and-its-uri-protocol