# codeigniter and htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I recently moved a functional codeigniter application to a new hosting provider and am running into what I think are challenges similar to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872505/codeigniter-configuri-protocolproblem). To summarize, my $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] and $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'] values are not being set unless I include the index.php reference in the URL.  I'm assuming this means that my .htaccess may be the culprit or a combination of issues.  Here's what I've done:

1. I edited codeigniter's config.php file to remove the index.php reference

   ```
   $config['index_page'] = '';
   ```
2. I created the following .htaccess file to remove the index.php from the URL

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On

     RewriteBase /

     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
   </IfModule>

   <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
     ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
   </IfModule>
   ```

   I've toggled between the RewriteRule [L] and [QSA,L] values and get the same behavior.
3. In the config.php file, I set the following value

   ```
   $config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
   ```

Using this configuration above, attempting to open www.mysite.com/test/1234 simply opens www.mysite.com.  But when I open www.mysite.com/**index.php**/test/1234, the $_SERVER[PATH_INFO] => /test/1234, but only opens www.mysite.com.

When I switch back to:

```
    $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

I can access www.mysite.com/test/1234 (without needing /index.php/), but the $_SERVER[PATH_INFO] value is not being set.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reference to PHP version in development and production environment, but at first glance I would try changing the cgi.fix-pathinfo setting:

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.cgi.fix-pathinfo

if php.ini editting is available.

Comment: php version is 5.3.17 and cgi.fix-pathinfo=1

Comment: try changing it to cgi.fix-pathinfo=0

Comment: I tested both cgi.fix-pathinfo=0 and cgi.fix-pathinfo=1 and am seeing the same behavior.