# Codeigniter routes not working since changing server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I've put into production a codeigniter website and I'm getting a strange behaviour that I'm not able to debug.

I'm using mod rewrite and all the pages points always to the home (default route) unless I use index.php in the url.

Example.

```
mywebsite.com/class/method -> all points to the same page
mywebsite.com/index.php/class/method -> points to the right page.
```

In the config: $config['index_page'] = "";

This is my htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|lib|robots\.txt|upload)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Website has been copied from one server to the other 1:1 (with different db configuration). I'm getting desperate as I've no idea what's happening here. mod_rewrite is enabled on hte server.

Thank you for any help, you'll save me from a nervous breakdown.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand the nature of your problem. Can you pls explain a little bit like what's not working and what's the expected behavior?

Comment: Try removing the forward slash before index.php.  Not sure it will make a difference but its worth a punt

Answer (score 0):

After almost giving up I found the issue.

The server didn't support $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] as it was disabled in apache.

For a quick fix you can change the setting to AUTO in config.php

Also read here: [Codeigniter $config['uri_protocol'] problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872505/codeigniter-configuri-protocolproblem)